# Is it possible to connect Li-Ion Batteries in series?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, lithium-ion

I've two identical 5V akku packs and need a 10V Power supply.
So is it possible to connect these two akku packs in series to reach this or are there any critical issues, that can occur?

Thank you!

Comment: Initially, you will get your 10 V, but when one shuts off before the other, that one needs to block the full voltage and interrupt or freewheel the current. Probably within reason. I would add an external freewheeling diode per pack and a capacitor, but I use both belt and suspenders.

Comment: *"Is it possible to connect Li-Ion Batteries in series?"* Nope.  Can't be done.  You are forever stuck with 4 V from lithium-ion batteries.  Things like electric cars are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be connecting two Li-ion batteries in series.  Li-ion batteries have a 3.6V output not 5V.

Whether they are in series is less of an issue than the current draw. You should be fine as long as you do not discharge the batteries too fast. That should not be an issue because li-ion batteries are very regulated, must pass safety standard tests, and there is likely a current limit on the output.

Many inexpensive off brand li-ion battery packs are not li-ion but NiMH. If the battery packs were shipped UPS, FedEx, or any way other than strictly ground, they are likely not Li-ion.  UPS and FedEx will not ship Li-ion batteries or battery packs unless they are packaged with a device that uses the batteries.

Comment: there are 5V and 6V LiIon battery packs . Actually "battery cell" for LiIon is 1.2V. 3.6V ones  and so on are  "packs" that contain cells internally, connected in series. You get  4.8V and 6V of nominal voltage , actually

Comment: They are 5V and 6V supplies battery powered boosted by a DC/DC converter.   The most common  Li-ion cell, Lithium Cobalt is 3.6v.  Lithium Manganese Oxide 3.7v, Lithium Nickel Manganese 3.6v, Lithium Iron Phosphate (very rare) 3.2v & 3.3v, Lithium Nickel Cobalt Aluminum Oxide 3.6v, and Lithium Titanate 2.4v.  No lithium ion is 1.2v.   You may be thinking of 1.2 Lithium Metal available as an AA battery and not rechargeable.  No Li-ion battery is available in an AA or AAA package and all are rechargeable.  http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/bu_216_summary_table_of_lithium_based_batteries

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be  problem as long as batteries provide same voltage. If one battery in chain is weak, that would stress it, would cause unexpected voltage and current drop. Thus you should not connect  batteries of different capacity or  "age" for that reason, because one would discharge at different rate. Large "chains" of packs may heat too much, providing reason to failure.

But you shouldn't not probably connect  "regulated" battery packs (and  5V-6V packs may come in this way) this way, they include electronics that may not work with that setup. IF it is  rated at unusual nominal voltage it's either a lie, or  there is voltage converter inside pack

Comment: Lithium cells are typically 3.7V or 3.3V nominal depending on technology. You're confusing them with Nickel Cadmium, which has a 1.2V cell.

Comment: @Finbarr most Li-ion are 3.6v but sold on eBay and Amazon as 3.7v which is incorrect.  It's a case where someone started using 3.7v and everyone else did not want to look inferior so they also started using 3.7. There is one lithium-ion chemistry, Li-manganese,  that is 3.7v but is much more expensive than the common 3.6v Li-colbalt.  Lithium Iron Phosphate are 3.2 or 3.3v but very rare.

Comment: @Misunderstood that's right, but LiNiMnCo are 3.85V, probably that spurred attempt to uplift nominal voltage of of LiIon and LiPo batteries